# Batch formatting of Date in multiple datasets

Tags: excel, date, csv, import, sas

i have extracted a number of excel spreadsheets into sas using proc import. however i now need to join the datasets together and need a uniform date format for all datasets. they are currently in character format and some are structured as '1999Q1' dates and some as '12/02/2013' dates. any help on how i can change formats for all dates in all datasets?

Comment: are they all numeric, strings or a mixture of both?

Comment: if you have 1999Q1 should that default to the beginning of the quarter, or for a date like 12/02/2013 is that to be 2013Q4?

Comment: sorry. should have been more clear. the date field is char for the Quarter dates. for the other dates, SAS picked them up as date fields. so for 1999Q1 it should be 31/03/1999. i need all dates to be monthend. i can do that for the dates but just dont know how to convert the quarter dates in text to month end dates.

Comment: Do you know the variable NAMES that you want to fix?  If they do not have date formats attached how will you know they should be dates instead of leaving them as character?  Do the variable names match across datasets?

Comment: Yep. All the relevant variables with dates in them have the variable name 'Date'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use INPUT() function to convert the strings to dates so that you can merge them. Let's make some sample datasets to simulate what you might have imported from your Excel sheets.

```
data have1;
  date='1999Q1';
  var1=1;
run;
data have2;
  date='02DEC2013'd ;
  format date yymmdd10.; 
  var2=2;
run;
```

Now let's get the variable names and types from those datasets.

```
proc contents data=work._all_ noprint out=contents; run;
```

We can use this metadata to write some code to convert the strings into dates.

```
filename code temp;
data _null_;
  set contents;
  where upcase(name)='DATE' and type=2;
  file code ;
  length dsn $41;
  dsn=catx('.',libname,memname);
  put 'data ' dsn ';'
    / '  set ' dsn ';'
    / '  datenum=input(date,anydtdte.);'
    / '  format datenum yymmdd10.;'
    / '  rename datenum=date date=datechar;'
    / 'run;'
  ;
run;

%inc code / source2 ;
```

Now we can merge the datasets.

```
data want ;
  merge have1 have2;
  by date;
run;
```